# MapBox didUpdateUserLocation called twice for every update

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

We use MapBox in one of our recent iOS 11 projects. In the project we have a phenomenon that cause big problems. For some reason the MapBox didUpdateUserLocation delegate method is called twice for every location update.

To illustrate the issue, we added this code which simply increase a class variable

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MGLMapViewDelegate Methods

- (void)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(nullable 
MGLUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"updatecounter = %i",updatecounter);
    updatecounter++;
}
```

The following sample output is generated:

```
2018-02-22 22:50:14.210199+0100 didUpdateUserLocation:] [Line 1830] updatecounter = 3
2018-02-22 22:50:14.210511+0100 didUpdateUserLocation:] [Line 1830] updatecounter = 3
2018-02-22 22:50:15.184880+0100 didUpdateUserLocation:] [Line 1830] updatecounter = 4
2018-02-22 22:50:15.187484+0100 didUpdateUserLocation:] [Line 1830] updatecounter = 4
2018-02-22 22:50:16.186877+0100 didUpdateUserLocation:] [Line 1830] updatecounter = 5
2018-02-22 22:50:16.189279+0100 didUpdateUserLocation:] [Line 1830] updatecounter = 5
....
```

If we remove the delegate connection to the viewController, the calls stop. Can anyone think of a reason what could cause MapBox to call the delegate twice for every update?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if you that's valid. I mean for one it's not 3,4,5,6,7,8 it's 3,3,4,4,5,5. So basically the delegate isn't called twice. Something else is. I'm just not sure what...

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. The output on line 1830 is generated by the NSLog you see in the delegate code. As you can see, there are two calls with only a couple of milliseconds between them. What's interesting is that the class variable is only incremented every two calls. This really puzzles us, by settings brekpoints in the delegate we can confirm that it is indeed called two times every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a case of mistakenly having multiple map views, causing multiple messages to be sent to the delegate. See [this thread](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/11292) for more information on how it was debugged.